# send html via phpmailer

Tags: php, html, css, phpmailer

I am using the PHP Mailer to send a HTML email. However, when i send the email below all the padding, margin, div sizes etc are gone (in Outlook). If I take a look at my gmail account it looks fine. In the iphone mail app the margin etc is gone too.

```
<div id="wrapper" style="width: 100%;">
<table width=600 style="margin:0 auto">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<div id="Banner" style="
    max-width: 640px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 60px;
    background-color: #75dcfc;
    width: 100%;
">
<div class="center" style="margin: auto;text-align: center;">   
  <img src="logourl" alt="test" style="max-width: 450px;padding-top: 0px;width: 50%;">
  </div>
  </div>

<div id="box" style="max-width: 640px;width: 100%;background-color: white;color: #696969;border-style: solid;border-width: 0px;text-align: center;border-color: #d3d3d3;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;overflow: hidden;padding: 0px;border-style: solid;height: 500px">
<div id="personalmsg" style="width: 100%;text-align: center;font-size: 22px;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;max-width: 400px;padding: 0px;">
    <p style="text-align: left;font-size: 17px;margin-top: 50px; color: #000;font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;">hello</p>


</div>

</div>
    <h2 id="link" style="text-align: center;max-width: 640px;margin: 0 auto;background-color: #75dcfc;padding-top: 15px;padding-bottom: 15px;width: 100%;"><a href="website" style="color: #fff;text-decoration: none;">Visit us</a></h2>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

As you can see i am using only inline css. however i dont get what i am doing wrong. Maybe it helps to show how i send the email:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->setFrom('my@email.com');
$mail->addAddress($email);

$mail->Subject = "Your Email";
$mail->Body = $html;
$mail->isHTML(true);
try {
    $mail->Send();  
}
catch (Exception $e) {

}
```

While $html is holding the HTML as a string.

I am thankful for any hin in the right direction

Comment: Make sure you're using full HTML markup. It doesn't look to be the case here, least not for what you posted. And/or it could be a local issue with your Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook is notorious for not supporting css well. All email clients have their own quirks with html and css, it's a lot of trial and error.

I can't answer your question any more than this, but I can offer you these references to recode your html with.

Microsoft offers this guide for html/css in outlook.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201.aspx#Word2007MailHTMLandCSS_Full

I use https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ often. It's been a trustworthy reference.

There are also web services that will render images of your email in various ways.  Litmus is a common one. I use it for emails generated and sent to customers at work.  The marketing department enjoys it as well.